# How to properly wait for API call to finish and show component in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, state

I have a simple react native main screen, with two components. One component is showing some information if the useState array is empty (`NoAnimals`). The other component is showing the data if the array is not empty (`RenderAnimals`). I have a useEffect call, where I make my API call, and set the loadings.

My problem is that no matter what I do, the `NoAnimals` component is always showing up first, even if the array is not empty, then switches to the other component.

How can I make sure, that if the array is not empty, do not show the `NoAnimals` component?

```
import RenderAnimals from '.....'
import NoAnimals from '.....'
import Loading from '.....'
import {getAnimals} from './myCoolAPI'

const App = () => {

const [animals, setAnimals] = useState([])
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(()=>{
 getAnimals()
    .then((res)=>{
    setAnimals(res)
    setLoading(false)
})
},[])


return(
<View>
            {
            loading 
            ? <Loading/> 
            : animals.length >= 1
            ? <RenderAnimals animals={animals}/> 
            : <NoAnimals/>  //<-- After loading set to false this renders first even if animals array is Not empty
            }
</View>
)
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem comes from the fact that your `animals` array is initiated to empty (`useState([])`).

You could initiate it to `null`. Once your data is loaded, it will be either empty or not.

Then you display your `animals` related content only if `animals` is an instance of Array (which means that your data has been loaded).

```
Array.isArray(animals) && (
    animals.length >= 1 ? <RenderAnimals animals={animals}/> : <NoAnimals/>
)
```

Or you could use a `ready` variable initiated to false.

```
[ready, setReady] = useState(false)
```

Then, once your API call is done, you set `ready` to `true`.

```
    useEffect(()=>{
     getAnimals()
        .then((res)=>{
        setAnimals(res)
        setLoading(false)
        setReady(true)
   })
   },[])
```

And you display your `animals` related content only when your data is loaded.

```
<View>
        {
        loading && <Loading/>
        ready && (
           {
             animals.length >= 1
             ? <RenderAnimals animals={animals}/> 
             : <NoAnimals/>
           }
        )
        }
</View>
```